# Integrate spring-boot-actuator metrics into SAP Cloud Platform Kibana

Tags: cloud-foundry, spring-boot-actuator, sap-cloud-platform

I've to a spring-boot-application hosted on sap cloud platform. I created custom metrics following that guide here: https://github.com/SAP/cf-java-logging-support

Now I'm struggling with getting those over to Kibana on SCP. The app already logs there using log4j but I seem to be missing some wiring as I can read. "Either post to the rest api or use the custom metric clients".

I only see application logs in kibana but not the custom metrics. Verified that they're there using the actuator endpoint:

> https://xxxxxxx.cfapps.eu10.hana.ondemand.com/actuator/metrics/HelloController.number.of.requests
>
> > {"name":"HelloController.number.of.requests","description":null,"baseUnit":null,"measurements":[{"statistic":"COUNT","value":4.0}],"availableTags":[{"tag":"unit","values":["requests"]}]}

Can anyone give me a hint so I get back on track?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

As described in the documentation of the [linked logging support libraries](https://github.com/SAP/cf-java-logging-support), you can either use their custom metric client to define them in your code and submit them to the logging stack. Alternatively you can also directly use the REST API to publish metrics of/for your application.

When they are correctly passed to the application-logging service, they will appear in Kibana. In the `Discover` tab you can select on the dropdown `custom-metrics-*` where by default `logstash-*` is pre-selected (on the left near the search bar). There you can find the reported metrics. It helps to select the `name` field into your search view, to find your desired values more easily.

You can also visualize the data in a graph based on the metrics for example.